# Erro sintático e logico no meu conversor de moedas

Tags: javascript

Olá, meu script tem um erro sintático e logico. Alguem poderia me ajudar por favor.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Conversor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="num" value=""> 
    <select id="moe1" onchange="converter()" style="display: inline-block;">
        <option value="Euro">€</option>
        <option value="Dolar">$</option>
        <option value="Real">R$</option>
        <option value="Libras">£</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="res" readonly="true">
    <select id="moe2" onchange="converter()" style="display: inline-block;">
        <option value="Euro">€</option>
        <option value="Dolar">$</option>
        <option value="Real">R$</option>
        <option value="Libras">£</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('num').addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
            converter();
        });
        function converter() {
            var moe1 = document.getElementById('moe1').value
            var moe2 = document.getElementById('moe2').value
            var num = document.getElementById('num').value
            var res = document.getElementById('res')
            if (moe1 == moe2) { 
                res.value = `${num}` 
            }
            if (moe1 == "Euro") {
                if (moe2 == "Dolar") {
                    var calc = num * 1.13
                    res.value = calc.toFixed(2)
                } else if (moe2 == "Real") {
                    var calc = num * 6.02
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Libras") {
                    var calc = num * 0.90
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } 
            if (moe1 == "Dolar") {
                if (moe2 == "Euro") {
                    var calc = num * 0.89
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Real") {
                    var calc = num * 5.33
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Libras") {
                    var calc = num * 0.79
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                }
            if (moe1 == "Real") {
                if (moe2 == "Euro") {
                    var calc = num * 0.17
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Dolar") {
                    var calc = num * 0.19
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Libras") {
                    var calc = num * 0.15
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } 
            if (moe1 == "Libras" && moe2 == "Euro") {
                if (moe2 == "Euro") {
                    var calc = num * 1.12
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Dolar") {
                    var calc = num * 1.26
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Real") {
                    var calc = num * 6.73
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oi João, você está basicamente pedindo para que alguém descubra onde está o erro no seu código. Isso é pedir que alguém trabalhe de graça pra você. Reduza seu código até descobrir o que causa o erro. Se persistir um dúvida depois de descobrir exatamente o que é o bug, aí sim, vc faz a pergunta, com um código que exemplifique só a dúvida. Mas não deixe de perguntar. Todo mundo erra.
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: Quando uma resposta resolve sua dificuldade marque-a (a melhor) como aceita. Veja como https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Answer (score 1):

Mano o que vc ta tentando fazer?

1° explique qual é sua duvida/dificuldade

2° o que já tentou?

3° se pedir para os outros resolverem nunca vai aprender.

4° Ta muito confuso seu código
if (moe1 == "Euro") {
if (moe2 == "Dolar") {

lol

if dentro de if não pode mano, não tem como usar uma estrutura condicional dentro de outra estrutura condicional.

e tem que printar teu resultado.

mas não deixe de pedir ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Falta de algumas chaves de fechamento `}`

comparação `if (moe1 == "Libras" && moe2 == "Euro") {` não justifica

certo é `if (moe1 == "Libras") {`

limitar o value do input id="num" a `0` e evitar números negativos

```
<input type="number" id="num" min=0 oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
```

```js
document.getElementById('num').addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
   converter();
});
       
        function converter() {
          var moe1 = document.getElementById('moe1').value
          var moe2 = document.getElementById('moe2').value
          var num = document.getElementById('num').value
          var res = document.getElementById('res')
          

            if (moe1 == moe2) { 
                res.value = `${num}` 
            }
            if (moe1 == "Euro") {
                if (moe2 == "Dolar") {
                    var calc = num * 1.13
                    res.value = calc.toFixed(2)
                } else if (moe2 == "Real") {
                    var calc = num * 6.02
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Libras") {
                    var calc = num * 0.90
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } 
            }
            if (moe1 == "Dolar") {
                if (moe2 == "Euro") {
                    var calc = num * 0.89
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Real") {
                    var calc = num * 5.33
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Libras") {
                    var calc = num * 0.79
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                }
            }
            if (moe1 == "Real") {
                if (moe2 == "Euro") {
                    var calc = num * 0.17
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Dolar") {
                    var calc = num * 0.19
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Libras") {
                    var calc = num * 0.15
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } 
            }
            if (moe1 == "Libras") {
                if (moe2 == "Euro") {
                    var calc = num * 1.12
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Dolar") {
                    var calc = num * 1.26
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                } else if (moe2 == "Real") {
                    var calc = num * 6.73
                    res.value = `${calc.toFixed(2)} `
                }
            }

        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Conversor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="num" value="" min="0"> 
    <select id="moe1" onchange="converter()" style="display: inline-block;">
        <option value="Euro">€</option>
        <option value="Dolar">$</option>
        <option value="Real">R$</option>
        <option value="Libras">£</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="res" readonly="true">
    <select id="moe2" onchange="converter()" style="display: inline-block;">
        <option value="Euro">€</option>
        <option value="Dolar">$</option>
        <option value="Real">R$</option>
        <option value="Libras">£</option>
    </select>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```